# Is there any way to remove column and rows numbers from DataFrame.from_dict?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, series

So, I have a problem with my dataframe from dictionary - python actually "names" my rows and columns with numbers.
Here's my code:

```
a = dict()
dfList = [x for x in df['Marka'].tolist() if str(x) != 'nan']
dfSet = set(dfList)
dfList123 = list(dfSet)
for i in range(len(dfList123)):
    number = dfList.count(dfList123[i])
    a[dfList123[i]]=number
sorted_by_value = sorted(a.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[1], reverse=True)
dataframe=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(sorted_by_value)
print(dataframe)
```

I've tried to rename columns like this:
`dataframe=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(sorted_by_value, orient='index', columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])`, but it gives me a error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'values'
```

Is there any way to fix it?

**Edit:**
Here's the first part of my data frame:

```
                     0     1
0                   VW  1383
1                 AUDI  1053
2                VOLVO   789
3                  BMW   749
4                 OPEL   621
5        MERCEDES BENZ   593
...
```

The 1st rows and columns are exactly what I need to remove/rename

Comment: Could you provide us with df sample? It would help to replicate the problem

Comment: Sure, just added

Answer (score 1):

#### `index` and `columns` are properties of your dataframe

As long as `len(df.index) > 0` and `len(df.columns) > 0`, i.e. your dataframe has nonzero rows and nonzero columns, you cannot get rid of the labels from your `pd.DataFrame` object. Whether the dataframe is constructed from a dictionary, or otherwise, is irrelevant.

What you *can* do is remove them from a **representation** of your dataframe, with output either as a Python `str` object or a CSV file. Here's a minimal example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])

print(df)
#    0  1  2
# 0  1  2  3
# 1  4  5  6

# output to string without index or headers
print(df.to_string(index=False, header=False))
# 1  2  3
# 4  5  6

# output to csv without index or headers
df.to_csv('file.csv', index=False, header=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

By sorting the `dict_items` object (`a.items()`), you have created a list. 
 You can check this with `type(sorted_by_value)`.  Then, when you try to use the `pd.DataFrame.from_dict()` method, it fails because it is expecting a dictionary, which has 'values', but instead receives a list.

Probably the smallest fix you can make to the code is to replace the line:

`dataframe=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(sorted_by_value)`

with:

`dataframe = pd.DataFrame(dict(sorted_by_value), index=[0])`.

(The `index=[0]` argument is required here because `pd.DataFrame` expects a dictionary to be in the form `{'key1': [list1, of, values], 'key2': [list2, of, values]}` but instead `sorted_by_value` is converted to the form `{'key1': value1, 'key2': value2}`.)

Another option is to use `pd.DataFrame(sorted_by_value)` to generate a dataframe directly from the sorted items, although you may need to tweak `sorted_by_value` or the result to get the desired dataframe format.

Alternatively, look at `collections.OrderedDict` (the documentation for which is [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)) to avoid sorting to a list and then converting back to a dictionary.

**Edit**

Regarding naming of columns and the index, without seeing the data/desired result it's difficult to give specific advice.  The options above will allow remove the error and allow you to create a dataframe, the columns of which can then be renamed using `dataframe.columns = [list, of, column, headings]`.  For the index, look at `pd.DataFrame.set_index(drop=True)` ([docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html)) and `pd.DataFrame.reset_index()` ([docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html)).