# Stopping to_excel overwriting text

Tags: python, excel, pandas.excelwriter

Update - I solved the below problem by adding rows to the data frame and then only writing the data frame to Excel once. Other readers may find [Add one row to pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715965/add-one-row-to-pandas-dataframe) helpful.

Update 2 - If you want to stop the header names being written to Excel then you may find this help [How do you remove the column name row from a pandas DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19781609/how-do-you-remove-the-column-name-row-from-a-pandas-dataframe).

Update 3 - If you want to remove the row numbers when you write the data frame to Excel then you may find this link helpful [Is there any way to remove column and rows numbers from DataFrame.from_dict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54065097/is-there-any-way-to-remove-column-and-rows-numbers-from-dataframe-from-dict).

I want Python to read a list of Amazon URLs from one Excel file (python.xlsx) and then populate a different Excel file (python2.xlsx) with the URL, product title and product price. I don't want to create a new Excel sheet for each product. I don't want existing data to be overwritten when new data is written to sheet1. And I don't need the to_excel command to write header names and row numbers to Excel either.

I looked at [How to write to an existing excel file without overwriting data (using pandas)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20219254/how-to-write-to-an-existing-excel-file-without-overwriting-data-using-pandas) but could not apply it to my problem.

Is there a way of stopping the header names and row numbers being written to Excel? Is there a way of stopping existing text being overwritten in the spreadsheet?

```
Row = 0
MaxRow = len(df)
while Row <= MaxRow:
    URL = (df.iloc[Row,0]) 
    headers  = {"User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36'}
    page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    title = soup.find(id="productTitle").get_text()
    price = soup.find(id="priceblock_ourprice").get_text()
    converted_price=float(price[1:6])
    df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Url':[URL],
                        'Title':[title.strip()],
                        'Price':[converted_price]})
    writer = ExcelWriter(r'C:\Users\HP\Documents\python2.xlsx')
    df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', startrow=Row,startcol=2)
    writer.save()
    Row = Row + 1
    if Row == MaxRow:
        break
```

Comment: You're writing to the same file, row by row. If the frame contains 10 rows, this means you'll keep overwiting the previous rows. At the very least increment `Row` by the actual number of rows. Better yet, open the file only once and create a *single* writer, outside the loop

Comment: So are you suggesting I write information to the data frame first and then write the data frame to Excel?